# Unable to center UIPopoverController

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller

In my app I'm trying to center a `UIPopoverController` (I've to use it because my app it's compatible with iOS 7). I'm trying to center it without success. My code to center it's the follow:

```
        SummaryViewController *summaryViewController = [[SummaryViewController alloc] init];
        summaryViewController.delegate = self;
        aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:summaryViewController];
        aPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(summaryViewController.view.frame.size.width, summaryViewController.view.frame.size.height);

        CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
        CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
        CGFloat popoverWidth = summaryViewController.view.frame.size.width;
        CGFloat popoverHeight = summaryViewController.view.frame.size.height;

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake((width - popoverWidth) / 2.0, (height -popoverHeight) / 2.0, 1, 1);
        [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```

It always shows me the popover in the left corner...
What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Just for further reference, `rect` in `presentPopoverFromRect` - 
The rectangle in view at which to anchor the popover window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  SummaryViewController *summaryViewController = [[SummaryViewController alloc] init];
  summaryViewController.delegate = self;
  aPopover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:summaryViewController];
  aPopover.popoverContentSize = CGSizeMake(summaryViewController.view.frame.size.width, summaryViewController.view.frame.size.height);

  CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
  CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
  CGFloat popoverWidth = summaryViewController.view.frame.size.width;
  CGFloat popoverHeight = summaryViewController.view.frame.size.height;

  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.size.width/2, self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 1, 1);
  [aPopover presentPopoverFromRect:rect inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:0 animated:YES];
```